# fortran f90 output not producing the expected result

Tags: fortran

I am trying to use this program to do iteration for X(i+1)=X(i)*50. After compilation, the output of the code is not the expected result. For instance, the value for X1 suppose to be 500, with X0=10. But in this case, it produced 0. What have i done wrongly.

```
program error

implicit none

integer :: i

real*8,dimension(4)  :: X

real*8  :: X0

X0=10

do i=0,3

  X(i+1)=(50.0d0)*X(i)

  write(*,*), i, X(i+1)

end do

end program error
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if X0 is assigned, but never used in the calculation. Shouldn't there be a line assigning X0 to X(1)? Or to make it more clear: X0 is not the same as X(1). In addition, arrays in fortran have default indices starting from 1, so the indices used in the loop are not correct.

```
program error

implicit none

integer :: i

real*8,dimension(5)  :: X <-- Extend by one element

real*8  :: X0

X0=10

X(1) = X0;

do i = 1,4 <-- Important!

    X(i+1)=(50.0d0)*X(i)

    write(*,*), i, X(i+1)

end do

end program error
```

Comment: thanks for the response. However, introducing it produced this error;

Comment: X(0)=X0;
  1
Warning: Array reference at (1) is out of bounds (0 < 1) in dimension 1

Comment: Sorry. Forgot that arrays in fortran start with index 1 by default. But I have to add, that in the question you also access X(i) with i == 0. I'll update the anwer.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: You're welcome. If this has solved your problem feel free to accept the answer :)

Comment: Since there is too much confusion about this, I will update the question with the full code example. Since we are using now X(1) as initial value, one has to extend the array by one element to achieve the same number of iterations then in the question.